# Can't Select SwiftUI TextField

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm not able to select and enter any text into my text fields. If I move them out of their current VStack and put them into the first VStack they work as expected. The buttons below them work just fine where they are so it doesn't seem as though the text fields are behind anything.

Here is my current layout.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var emailAddress = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @State var showingAlert = false
    @State var error = ""
    @State var showCollections = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .white,]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)

                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Color.white
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                        TextField("Email", text: $emailAddress, onEditingChanged: { edit in

                        }, onCommit: {

                        })
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 80, height: 41, alignment: .center)
                            .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                            .background(Color.init(red: 211.0/255.0, green: 211.0/255.0, blue: 211.0/255.0))
                            .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .padding(.top, 15)
                            .padding(.bottom, 10)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)

                        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 80, height: 41, alignment: .center)
                            .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                            .background(Color.init(red: 211.0/255.0, green: 211.0/255.0, blue: 211.0/255.0))
                            .textContentType(.password)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)

                        Button(action: signIn) {
                            Text("Sign In")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 80, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(20, antialiased: true)

                        Button(action: createAccount) {
                            Text("Don't have an account? Create one.")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 80, height: 50, alignment: .center)

                        Button(action: forgotPassword) {
                            Text("Forgot password?")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 80, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(20)
            }
        }
    }

    func signIn() {

    }

    func createAccount() {

    }

    func forgotPassword() {

    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried (a) removing the outer `VStack` along with (b) removing the `ZStack`? At least that would eliminate the `ZStack` as the culprit.

Comment: @dfd I tried moving the text fields to the outer VStack just below the Text label and they work there. I can't figure out why they aren't selectable in the current VStack though. The buttons work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definetely something odd going on, however, you can workaround it by using `zIndex()` on your `TextField` and `SecureField`:

```swift
TextField("Email", text: $emailAddress, onEditingChanged: { edit in }, onCommit: { })
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 80, height: 41, alignment: .center)
    .textFieldStyle(.plain)
    .background(Color.init(red: 211.0/255.0, green: 211.0/255.0, blue: 211.0/255.0))
    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .padding(.top, 15)
    .padding(.bottom, 10)
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .zIndex(1)

SecureField("Password", text: $password)
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 80, height: 41, alignment: .center)
    .textFieldStyle(.plain)
    .background(Color.init(red: 211.0/255.0, green: 211.0/255.0, blue: 211.0/255.0))
    .textContentType(.password)
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .zIndex(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I'm still curious as to what is going on to cause it not to work without the zIndex.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know! It seems the Buttons are somehow occupying more space than they should, and because they are after in the hierarchy, they "obstruct" your textfields invisibly. By using zIndex, you just invert their order. It is weird though, because drawing a border around the buttons does not show that. I guess we will have to leave it to the fact that we are still in beta 4.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but another possible solution could be defining the hit area of the button, using `contentShape()`. However, zIndex() is much more simple. I just mention it for completeness. ;-)